# Destination Folder Batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I currently use a .bat file

I'm able to copy a `test.cfg` file in a folder named `testVersion434` using `copy test.cfg testVersion434`.

Unfortunately I am unable to copy the file `test.cfg` to a folder that begins with `testXXXXXXXX`

I'll have in the future Folders `testVersion43x` that will create , and I would copy `test.cfg` in all folders who begin with `test`

I can list all of them with `dir test*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enumerate the target folders and execute a copy operation for each one

```dos
for /d %%a in ("c:\folders\test*") do copy "c:\file\test.cfg" "%%~fa"
```

The `for /d` command will iterate over the indicated set of folders and, for each one, the code after the `do` clause is executed, with `%%a` holding a reference to the folder being iterated. `%%~fa` is the full path of the folder.